# problem with spark structured streaming after restart

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

I have a simple pyspark code,which reads data from kafka and write aggregated records to oracle with foreachbatch.I have set checkpointLocation on hdfs dir and it works well.when I kill application and start code without any change, it gives the following error:

```
Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2672)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2608)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2860)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2802)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:952)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2228)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2249)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2268)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2293)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1021)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:406)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1020)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:424)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectToPython$1(Dataset.scala:3688)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$2(Dataset.scala:3858)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:510)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3856)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:95)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3856)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:3685)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor76.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.sendCommand(ClientServerConnection.java:244)
        at py4j.CallbackClient.sendCommand(CallbackClient.java:384)
        at py4j.CallbackClient.sendCommand(CallbackClient.java:356)
        at py4j.reflection.PythonProxyHandler.invoke(PythonProxyHandler.java:106)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.PythonForeachBatchHelper$.$anonfun$callForeachBatch$1(ForeachBatchSink.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.PythonForeachBatchHelper$.$anonfun$callForeachBatch$1$adapted(ForeachBatchSink.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.ForeachBatchSink.addBatch(ForeachBatchSink.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$17(MicroBatchExecution.scala:660)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:95)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$16(MicroBatchExecution.scala:658)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:375)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:658)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:255)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:375)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:218)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.$anonfun$runStream$1(StreamExecution.scala:307)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:285)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:208)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /checkpoints/summary_cbs_sms/state/0/46/2212.zip
```

spark version: 3.3.0

master: yarn

state store : rocksdb(both hdfs and rocksdb have this problem)

source config:

```
inputDF=spark\
  .readStream\
  .format("kafka")\
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",kafka_url)\
  .option("subscribe", "cbs_sms")\
  .option("failOnDataLoss",False) \
  .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger",10000)\
  .option("minOffsetsPerTrigger",10)\
  .load()\
  .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
```

sink config:

```
summaryDF4.writeStream \
  .foreachBatch(SaveToOracle)\
  .option("checkpointLocation", "hdfs://ip:9000/checkpoints/summary_cbs_sms")\
  .outputMode("update") \
  .start()\
  .awaitTermination()
```

application is running and I get this error for every batch.

update1:

It only happens when I kill the application through yarn

update2:

I have tried other version of hadoop and spark,But there was still problem. I have tried to test code without foreachBatch and it worked.
I don't know why but when I removed try-except from my function it worked.I have changed code and add df.persist and df.unpersist in exception part and my problem is completely solved.